# Emacs lisp question

Tags: c, emacs, elisp

I want this function to compile the contents of the current buffer(a C file) and show the output(a.out) if the compilation succeeded

```
(defun c-shell-compile ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (if (equal (shell-command (concat "gcc " (buffer-file-name))) 
             "(Shell command succeeded with no output)")
      (shell-command "./a.out")
    ;;Else show the errors        
    ))

 (add-hook 'c-mode-hook
           (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "\C-c\C-c") 'c-shell-compile)))
```

But it does not seem to be working, if the compilation succeeds it just says "(Shell command succeeded with no output)" without showing the output.

Answers or directions very much appreciated.

Comment: Consider using 'compile which also creates a special *compilation* buffer to check compiler output/errors.

Comment: That's what I tried at first but using shell-command seems more flexible to customize.

Comment: You can customize most elisp functions using hooks: See code below.

Even if hooks are not available you can use defadvice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of shell-command is the status.  So don't compare it to a string but to 0

```
(defun c-shell-compile ()
   (interactive)
   (save-buffer)
   (when (= 0 (shell-command (concat "gcc " (buffer-file-name))))
         (shell-command "./a.out")))
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! , and now C is as interactive as python(for small files atleast) ;)

Comment: Btw , had to add a ) after (buffer-file-name)

Answer (score 2):

And yet another solution:

```
M-x compile RET gdb <filename> && a.out
```

You can get the default compilation command to be that by setting the [variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Variables.html#Variables) `compile-command` either as a [file variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables), [directory variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html#Directory-Variables), in a [mode hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html#Hooks), or [manually](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Examining.html#Examining).  This works well if `a.out` doesn't require user input from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

This version uses 'compile (as mentioned in a comment above this will let you jump to error messages etc.)

```
(defun c-compile ()
  (interactive)
  (compile (concat "gcc " (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))
                   " && ./a.out")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like most elisp code, you can extend the compilation process using hooks:

This is the way you should go. Sooner or later you will want to check compilation errors, save dependent buffers, ... and don't wan't to reinvent the wheel:

```
(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 
      (lambda (buffer desc)
        (when (string-equal desc "finished\n")
        (shell-command "./a.out"))))
```